# Remove default.aspx start up web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to remove [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzrVR.png)? This always pop up as default everytime I create a new project on C# ASP.NET web form Application (default.aspx)

Comment: Eliminate what? The split view? The default project template? And why are you creating new Web Forms apps in the first place? It's a dead technology.

Comment: I'm starting a new project and every time I create a new project that page is always there. Like it is already there.

Comment: What is always there? The default content? Then create an empty project. It's one of the options when creating a project.

Comment: New project>ASP.NET Web Form Application>ok   when I click ok that thing is already in there and named as default.aspx not only that, there is also a web form name about.aspx which contains also bout ASP page.

Comment: You clicked OK....and just breezed by the option for creating an empty project...

Comment: Yes, the default content is always there which is the asp.net page. the one on the image I've posted. I think it should be just a blank form in there when you create a new project

Comment: What option should I go to?

Comment: I've told you. Choose the empty option. That's it. You're making this far harder than it should be. Just slow down and choose your options carefully when making a project.

Comment: Though I choose blank form the thing is still there by default

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

(as in Visual studio 2015)

New Project >> Web >> Asp.Net Web Application >>

Now, select "Empty" template at the top & check "Web Form" box in the second block.

This would create

1. A solution file (.sln) : Required to group together all related files of the project
2. References: It adds references to system/framework level dlls, by default. You can keep whichever required & delete the one which are not.
3. App_Data: Empty folder.
4. Models: Empty folder.
5. Global.asax: Required file for a web forms project.
6. packages.config & web.config: These are related to configuration files and are required.

The above set of files define an empty web form project.

You can add new files/folders to this project i.e. aspx or other types. 

e.g.: name_of_your_choice.aspx - this creates an empty .aspx file with minimal required markup.

Why does visual studio adds those set of files in a new project? 
These files are created as per the template selected in project creation wizard.

If you still find default files & folders with Empty option, you can create a blank solution file & create web project from scratch.